# empty view when using ngResource

Tags: angularjs

I create such factory:

```
angular.module('todoApp', ['ngResource']).factory('taskService', ['constantsService', function($resource, constantsService){
var serverUrl = constantsService.server_url;
return {
    add: function(task){ $resource(serverUrl + '/api/task/', {task: task}, {'query':  {method:'POST'}});}
}
}]);
```

When I add ngResource to my module, I get a blank html element instead of my application.

Comment: What does chrome console say?

Comment: same here on 1.0.8, nothing in the console appear in the console and ng-view is empty, just added ,["ngResource"] to my module

Comment: This exact same thing happens for me. No errors in console, no view built. Best google search result is this page but no solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

I add ngResource to my module when i create it, not in factory, and it works.

Comment: Your solution here is unclear. You said above "[w]hen I add ngResource to my module, I get a blank html element" and now you're saying that it fixes it. Can you elaborate on your solution and what the problem was?